# Free image editor with tablet pressure support on Windows?

Tags: windows, graphics-tablet

I know that Paint.NET used to have pressure support, but they pulled it out several versions ago and refuse to add it back in. Are there any other decent free Windows image editors that support pressure for tablet users?

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/25451/looking-for-a-good-free-image-editor

Comment: @Sathya: Except it has nothing to do with tablet support.

Comment: I didn't say it was duplicate, did I ? It was a suggestion to have a look at the programs mentioned there.

Comment: @Sathya: I just think a more appropriate related question would be one dealing with tablet support in apps, free or otherwise. Sorry if I came off as offensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through Gimp's help files it shows support for tablets with pressure input:

http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-input-devices

Comment: I'd like to use GIMP single window mode, but it's not in 2.6 and I've yet to find Windows builds of 2.7. I can't handle that multi-window mode, too many terrible memories of old Visual Basic 4. Chances are this'll be what I go with in the end, though I'd still love to hear of alternatives!

Comment: Well, aren't I a bucket of derp. Found 2.7.1 for Windows in the same place I found 2.6.10, just under a different category. That'll teach me.